# Oracle APEX Pre-Rendering Points - APEX 21.1

Tags: oracle-apex

Trying to get a description/explanation of the different Rendering points in the APEX Layout - specifically what the difference is between `After Header` and `Before Regions` and when you would use one over the other. I understand one is "After" the HTTP header and the other is most likely before APEX paints the regions in the DOM, but wondering more when you would use them. Seems to me you would just put everything in `Before Header`, no?

I've looked through the APEX docs and was not able to find anything regarding this, but possible I'm not using the correct terminology with my search keywords. Can anyone provide links to help me learn more? My Google-fu has given me a few hits, but for older versions of APEX.

Answer (score 1):

I've mostly used `Before Header` myself and it has been enough, but I think that the different rendering points may come into play if you need to deal with branches i.e. doing things differently depending on what happens in various phases of page load.

I found a snippet from an e-book that somewhat describes those different points: [Oracle Application Express (APEX) - Build Powerful Data-Centric Web Apps with APEX](https://ebookreading.net/view/book/EB9780071843065_16.html) (*Page Execution Points*). I know it ain't much, but maybe this sheds some light or helps you further in your quest.

Comment: Somehow missed this response. Thanks @Captain (even if a few years late! ;)